# Combine subqueries used to retrieve values for comparison into a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_value FROM submissions WHERE username = (
  SELECT username FROM submissions WHERE id = '1'
) AND number = (
  SELECT number FROM submissions WHERE id = '1'
) AND tstmp < (
  SELECT tstmp FROM submissions WHERE id = '1'
);
```

Notice how I am using this query to find all rows with similar column values, but with a timestamp value that is less than row number 1.

This works for me, but I was wondering, is there a way I could combine the three subqueries into one? They all select information from the same table, so I thought it might be possible, but I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: show your table structure, id is primary key or else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could merge the subqueries into one and use it as a derived table in a join. Please try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_value 
FROM submissions s
JOIN (
    SELECT username, number, tstmp 
    FROM submissions WHERE id = 1
) o ON s.number = o.number AND s.username = o.username AND s.tstmp < o.tstmp
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much!